# Cannot Read Serial Data Recieved to Textbox

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to write my serial Data received to a textbox from a class to my form.

I am using the code:

```
Public Shared Sub DataReceviedHandler(sender As Object, e As SerialDataReceivedEventArgs)

Dim sp As SerialPort = CType(sender, SerialPort)
Dim indata As String = sp.ReadExisting()
frmRBATestMain.RichTextBox1.AppendText("Data Received:" + Environment.NewLine)
frmRBATestMain.RichTextBox1.AppendText(indata + Environment.NewLine)
End Sub
```

For some reason it will not write to the RichTextBox, it always stays blank??

However if I run it in console it works.  Why does this not work?

I am trying to replicate this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived(v=vs.90).aspx

I have a form that is reading from a class.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you set a breakpoint in that code and run your app?

Comment: are you trying to run the console and get the data receiver to a textbox in a form or simply push a button to send command and gather the data received?

Comment: @KenWhite It shows it writing to the textbox the data recieved but never goes.

Comment: @noidea I am trying to write the data recieved to a textbox on a form from a class.vb

Comment: Standard VB.NET lossage.  You cannot use a *type name* like `frmRBATestMain` in code that runs on a worker thread.  It will in effect create a *new* instance of the frmRBATestMain class, you cannot see it because its Show() method was never called.  You must instead use a proper reference to the one you are actually looking at.  Usually `Me` if you do it right.  And use its BeginInvoke() method to update the text box.  Do beware that this kind of code always works very poorly, you'll hammer the UI thread with too many invokes and that makes it go catatonic as well.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah you're right, that's why i asked if he was sending a command from a button..

Comment: @HansPassant How would I write this I don't care if its written poorly.

Comment: @noidea How would I write this I don't care if its written poorly.

Comment: @CarlRoe i asked you a question in my answer to adapt the code..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(sender As System.Object, e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
    ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
End Sub

Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String)
    If Me.TextBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim x As New SetTextCallBlack(AddressOf ReceivedText)
        Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
    Else
        Me.TextBox1.Text &= [text]
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yea ofc, i'm not making up code. How do you open the connection?